# Vine like flowering plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

What could be this plant? Is this actually vine? Location is India

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what is called purslane in the US. Sunny location and can tolerate low water, similar to moss rose.

Comment: I tried looking for purslane but couldn't find any similar looking leaves.

Comment: I meant to say it may not be the same variety as in the US.